# Value not updating from a Editor Tempale Partial Page View using three DropDownLists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, editortemplates

I have a EditorTemplate in a PartialPageView for a DateTime which has three DropDownLists for the day, month, and year. When I try to update the values the postback Date is always 01/01/0001. Any ideas?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Value.Day, Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString(), Selected = i == Model.Value.Day ? true: false})) %>
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Value.Month, Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i), Selected = i == Model.Value.Month ? true : false }))%>
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Value.Year, Enumerable.Range(1900, 110).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString(), Selected = i == Model.Value.Year ? true : false }))%>
```

Comment: Post your controller code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle this case you might need to [write a custom model binder](http://www.longcloudtech.com/Blogs/Yankiwi/post/2010/04/21/Updating-Scott-Hanselmane28099s-DateTime-Custom-Model-Binder-%28DateAndTimeModelBinder%29.aspx).